# Error in JDBC-Teradata Connectivity

Tags: jakarta-ee, jdbc, teradata

I have tried connecting to teredata DB through JDBC. I am using the jars 'terajdbc4.jar' and 'tdgssconfig.jar', but I am getting a `ClassNotFoundException` and `NoClassDefFoundError` for something kind of `com.ncr.teradata.jtdgss.TdgssManager` is not found.

Please help me to find a solution. I have provided my code snippet followed by the error log.
The user name and passwords are correct as connect to the teradata DB through UNIX using that ID.

```
public class HelloTeradataJDBC {


  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    String url="jdbc:teradata://10.10.***.**/DBS_PORT= 1025/DATABASE= ******/TMODE=ANSI,CHARSET=UTF8";

    try{
    Class.forName("com.ncr.teradata.TeraDriver");
    Connection conn=DriverManager.getConnection(url, "*****", "******");
    //Connection conn=DriverManager.getConnection(connurl, "javauser1", "password1");

    String query="select * from xi.san_emp";


    PreparedStatement stmt=conn.prepareStatement(query);
    ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery();
    while(rs.next()) {
        String col1=rs.getString(1);
        System.out.println("col1="+col1);
    }
    }catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/ncr/teradata/jtdgss/TdgssManager
    at com.ncr.teradata.TeraEncrypt.getTDgssVersion(TeraEncrypt.java:548)
    at com.ncr.teradata.jdbc_4.parcel.ConfigFeatureTdgss.<init>(ConfigFeatureTdgss.java:44)
    at com.ncr.teradata.jdbc_4.statemachine.InitDBConfigState.action(InitDBConfigState.java:68)
    at com.ncr.teradata.jdbc_4.statemachine.LogonController.run(LogonController.java:50)
    at com.ncr.teradata.jdbc_4.TDSession.<init>(TDSession.java:150)
    at com.ncr.teradata.jdbc_3.ifjdbc_4.TeraLocalConnection.<init>(TeraLocalConnection.java:89)
    at com.ncr.teradata.jdbc.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:50)
    at com.ncr.teradata.TeraDriver.connect(TeraDriver.java:214)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:582)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:185)
    at HelloTeradataJDBC.main(HelloTeradataJDBC.java:15)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ncr.teradata.jtdgss.TdgssManager
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work. THe Driver name is com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver instead of com.ncr.teradata.TeraDriver which I believe is dated.

```
Class.forName("com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver");
conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:teradata://"+servername+"/databasename="+this.username+",user="+this.username+",password="+this.password);
```

Comment: There is no such Package and class specified as 'com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver' in the jar i am using terajdbc4.jar .
Please post the link of the jar that is dated as of now.
The class missing is 'com.ncr.teradata.jtdgss.TdgssManager'.

Comment: It is available here. http://downloads.teradata.com/download/connectivity/jdbc-driver